# Vue js - image map area with v-for

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, area

I'm trying to create a *piano* (which has 7 octaves and 88 keys) and i have a `img` that contains 12 keys.
i'm trying to use `v-for` to iterate over the pictures and play notes in their fitting octave, but for some reason vue doesn't recognize the `index` from my `v-for` loop. 
my code:

```
<div v-for="(k, i) in keys" :key="k.id">
        {{i+1}}
        <img :src="k" alt="" usemap="#piano-map">
        <map name="piano-map" :key="k.id">
            <area target="" alt="k" title="k" @click="piano.note('c'+ parseInt(i+1)).play()" coords="2,0,81,267" shape="rect">
        </map>
    </div>
```

any ideas?

Comment: What's inside your `k` variable, line 3 suggests its a string because `:src` accepts a string, but on line 4, you are using a property of it, suggesting its an object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is cause by your re-use of names/ids's,

The output after unwinding the loop goes like:

```
<div>
    1
    <img :src="keys[0]" alt="" usemap="#piano-map">
    <map name="piano-map" :key="keys[0].id">
        <area target="" alt="k" title="k" @click="piano.note('c'+ parseInt(1)).play()" coords="2,0,81,267" shape="rect">
    </map>
</div>
<div>
    2
    <img :src="keys[1]" alt="" usemap="#piano-map">
    <map name="piano-map" :key="keys[1].id">
        <area target="" alt="k" title="k" @click="piano.note('c'+ parseInt(2)).play()" coords="2,0,81,267" shape="rect">
    </map>
</div>
```

As you can see in the above output of your code, there are multiple elements with the same name.

The causes your bug, clicking on any of your images causes the *first* element with that name to activate, so it always triggers note 1.

To solve this, give every element an name based on their index:

```
<div v-for="(k, i) in keys" :key="k.id">
    {{i+1}}
    <img :src="k" alt="" :usemap="'#piano-map-' + i">
    <map :name="'#piano-map-' + i" :key="k.id">
        <area target="" alt="k" title="k" @click="piano.note('c'+ parseInt(i+1)).play()" coords="2,0,81,267" shape="rect">
    </map>
</div>
```

Since every image activating the first entry feels like Vue is ignoring your index, you probably thought that instead of the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `parseInt(i+1)` the `i` is already an *integer* you could use it directly as parameter as follow :

```
    <area target="" alt="k" title="k" @click="piano.note(i).play()" coords="2,0,81,267" shape="rect">
```

and in your method use it like :

```
  note(i){
     var i=i+1;
     var c='c'+i;
     ....
  }
```

you have to create unique name for each map as follow :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
   },
   methods:{
      note(i){
      console.log(i)
      }
   }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="description" content="Vue.delete">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.1/vue.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
     <div v-for="i in 8" :key="i">
        {{i+1}}
        <img :src="i" alt="aa" :usemap="'#piano-map'+i">
        <map :name="'piano-map'+i" :key="i">
            <area target="" alt="k" title="k" @click="note('c'+ parseInt(i+1))" coords="2,0,81,267" shape="rect">
        </map>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Im using the parseInt cause i need to add one to the note(octaves start from 1 not zero). 
i also tried logging i in different places inside the <area> tag but it doesnt work, only outside of it...

Comment: on logging i from inside a function called from the @click of a <area> element i always get 0 regardless of the iterable it is.

Comment: you're welcpme, the problem was the uniqueness of names?

Comment: yes, of the piano-map, they were all refering to the same one...such a silly mistake 

Comment: it works perfectly now, with the parseInt(i+1) haha, which makes it inline and much more convinient...